# WPML CMS Nav and Custom Nav_Walker Undefined Property Notices

Tags: menus, walker, plugin-wpml

I have a Nav_Walker class to work with the Super Fish menu. And it works well. Now that I added WPML CMS Nav however I am getting notices like:

```
notice: Undefined property: wpml_ls_menu_item::$current in /srv/www/sub.domain.com/current/web/app/themes/theme/lib/setup.php on line 313
```

on that line there is

```
$element->classes[] = ( $element->current || $element->current_item_ancestor ) ? 'active' : '';
```

It also mentions that `$element->current_item_ancestor` is not defined as a property either. When I do a var_dump inside the class:

```
var_dump($element->current_item_ancestor);
```

I do get boolean false.

```
/srv/www/sub.domain.com/current/web/app/themes/theme/lib/setup.php:314:boolean false
```

And that was for the second property undefined notice.

Is this because `display_element` is a private method and I should not call it (directly) this way? How can I remedy this?

Full class here below:

```
class Nav_Walker extends \Walker_Nav_Menu
{

    function display_element($element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth = 0, $args, &$output)
    {
        $element->has_children = ! empty($children_elements[$element->ID]);
        $element->classes[] = ( $element->current || $element->current_item_ancestor ) ? 'active' : '';
        //var_dump($element->current_item_ancestor);
        $element->classes[] = ( $element->has_children ) ? 'has-children' : '';
        parent::display_element($element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output);
    }
    /*
     * At the start of each element, output a <li> and <a> tag structure.
     *
     * Note: Menu objects include url and title properties, so we will use those.
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     */
    function start_el(&$output, $object, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0)
    {

        $item_html = '';
        $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat('', $depth) : '' ); // code indent
        $line = ( $depth < 2  ? "\n" : '' ); // new line
        $this->curItem = $object;
        parent::start_el($item_html, $object, $depth, $args);
        $curItem = $object;
        $classes = empty($object->classes) ? array() : (array) $object->classes;

        if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
            $classes[] = 'current ';
        }

        $class_names = esc_attr(implode(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $object)));

        // Build html markup
        $output .= $indent .'<li id="nav-menu-item-'. $object->ID . '" class="' . $class_names . '">'   .   $line;

        // link attributes
        $attributes  = ! empty($object->attr_title) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr($object->attr_title) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty($object->target)     ? ' target="' . esc_attr($object->target) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty($object->xfn)        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr($object->xfn) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty($object->url)        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr($object->url) .'" itemprop="url"' : '';
        $attributes .= ( $object->has_children )      ? ' aria-haspopup="true"' : '';

        $item_html = sprintf(
            '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
            $args->before,
            $attributes,
            $args->link_before,
            apply_filters('the_title', $object->title, $object->ID),
            $args->link_after,
            $args->after
        );

        // Complete the html markup by apply filter so other plugins can hook into it.
        $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_html, $object, $depth, $args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked the variable with isset to see whether or not it contained a value:

```
$element->classes[] = ( isset($element->current) || isset($element->current_item_ancestor )) ? 'active' : '';
```

This solved the notice issue. And this seems to do the trick. Guess I over thought things here. Now I can start adding some content in Arabic and see start using the language switcher.